# Function not passing into model pop up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a model,
I am trying to pass a function as a parameter in the pop up...
but the model function is not taking the parameter...
providing my code below...

I am trying to pass function in this model **cnfrmMsgMdlEs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Is your code reflect your problem?

Comment: sorry i pasted wrong code i need to edit it